# python function call syntax ... result = foo() ['abc']

Tags: python, syntax

```
number = droid.readPhoneState()['result']['incomingNumber']
```

What are 'result' and 'incomingNumber' in this syntax -- are they not parameters?

How are they related to the function `readPhoneState`?

```
import android

droid = android.Android()
droid.startTrackingPhoneState()

number = droid.readPhoneState()['result']['incomingNumber']

if number != None:
  droid.speak('Call from '+str(number))
else:
  droid.makeToast('No incoming call')
```

Comment: You don't need to mark code sections like you did. Just indent by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`droid.readPhoneState()` returns a dict of dicts. Equivalent code:

```
outerDict = droid.readPhoneState()
innerDict = outerDict['result']
number = innerDict['incomingNumber']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,
where is this syntax documented

Answer (score 2):

`result` and `incomingNumber` are keys to a dictionary or an instance of a class that implements method `__getitem__`. This means that `readPhoneState()` returns a dictionary object, which supposed to have a key `result` and the corresponding value is a dictionary object which supposed to have a key `incomingNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

the interpretation is that `droid.readPhoneState()` returns a `dict`, whose value corresponding to the key `'result'` is another `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

readPhoneState() is the method and it returns a dictionary object.

The dictionary object contains the property `result` which is also a dictionary object containing the property `incomingNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, readPhoneState() returns a dictionary where values are, again, dictionaries.

With this syntax, you get the dictionary - returned by readPhoneState() - associated with key 'result' and ask it for the value whose key is 'incomingNumber'.